# Finite dimensional vector space $V$ and $\operatorname{End}_k(V)$.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

This is a homework problem. I want to solve it independently as best I can, so please only give awesome hints.

> Let $k$ be a field. Let $V$ be a vector space over $k$. I want to prove that $V$ is finite dimensional if and only if for every $\varphi \in \operatorname{End}_k(V)$ there exist $p \in k[x]$ such that $p(\varphi)=0$.

I have proved the forward implication and am stuck on the converse. Here is my proof of the forward implication:

Suppose $V$ is a $k$-vector space of dimension $n$. We know $k[x]$ is an infinite dimensional $k$-vector space and we know that $dim(V)=dim(ker(f))+dim(im(f))$ for any $k$-linear ring homomorphism $f:V \rightarrow W$, where $V$ and $W$ are any $k$-vector spaces. Fix $g \in End_k(V)$ and define $f_g:k[x] \rightarrow End_k(V)$ by $p \mapsto p(g)$. I will show that $f_g$ is a linear transformation and that $dim(im(f_g))$ is finite. This will force $dim(ker(f_g))$ to be gigantic, because $dim(k[x])=dim(ker(f_g))+dim(im(f_g))$ and $dim(k[x])$ is infinite. In particular, it will imply that there is $p \in k[x]$ such that $p(g)=0$, which is what we want.

Let $p,q \in k[x]$ and $z\in k$. Then $f_g(zp+q)=zp(g)+q(g)$. So $f_g$ is a $k$-linear ring homomorphism. By Corollary 11 on page 416 (Dummit & Foote), $dim(End_k(V))=n^2$, since $V$ is of finite dimension $n$. As $im(f_g)$ is a subspace of $End_k(V)$, we have that $im(f_g)$ is finite dimensional. Therefore $ker(f_g)$ is infinite dimensional. That is, there is $p \in k[x]$ such that $p(g)=0$.

Please critique my proof.

For the converse proof, I am stuck. But here are my attempts:

Suppose that for every $\varphi \in End_k(V)$ there is $p \in k[x]$ such that $p(\varphi)=0$. Let $g \in End(V)$ and define $f_g:k[x] \rightarrow End_k(V)$ by $p \mapsto p(g)$. By assumption there is $q \in k[x]$ such that $q(g)=0$. Then, I think, $ker(f_g)= (q)$. It is known from an example in Dummit and Foote on page 410 that $dim(k[x]/(q))=deg(q)$. Thus, if I can prove that $f_g$ is surjective, then it will follow that $End_k(V)$ is finite dimensional, because if $f_g$ is surjective then $k[x]/(q) \cong End_k(V)$. But I have not been able to prove surjectivity.

My only other observation is that, given the converse assumption, there exist $a_{n-1},...,a_1,a_0$ such that $a_{n-1}(id_v)^{n-1}+...+a_1id_v+a_0 =0$, which implies that $a_{n-1}v+...+a_1v+a_0=0$ for every $v \in V$.

So, any ideas? :) Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The forward proof looks fine, though you say $f\colon V \to W$ is a ring homomorphism when $V$ and $W$ are not rings.  But the $f$ you care about is $f_g$ which *is* a ring homomorphism so basically you just need to reword that.

So you've proved $A \Rightarrow B$, for the converse don't give a direct proof ($B \Rightarrow A$), instead prove the contrapositive $\neg A \Rightarrow \neg B$.  So assume $V$ is infinite dimensional and write down an explicit endomorphism that is not annihilated by a polynomial.

Comment: Thanks. I was thinking of $V$ and $W$ as both vector spaces and k-modules. I guess I should change that. I will try to do what you have suggested. Thank you for your help.

Comment: I should note also that I don't think your strategy will work.  $f_g$ is very likely **not** surjective, even when $V$ is finite dimensional.

Comment: Yeah, I was very doubtful of it but it was my only idea at the time.

Comment: I'm not sure if what I've done works, I didn't even use the assumption that $V$ is infinite dimensional. I want to show there is $\varphi \in End(V)$ such that for all $p \in k[x]$, $p(\varphi) \neq 0$. Right? Doesn't the identity work?

Comment: Never mind that last comment. I think I got it. I suppose ~$A$ and $B$ and found a contradiction.